# Google pubsub - metric for number of messages published to topic every day

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

How can we see how many number of messages published to a topic every day (or say every hour)? any metric available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name implies, the metrics tab features a lot of Pub/Sub metrics, for example published message count over time.

To get there, click on the topic and then on metrics.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks a lot @vpriesner  for answering, i see there are 15 different metrics available for a topic and in that list it does not have  "published message count over time" or similar one , can you please point me to the documentation?

Comment: 15? I can only see 6, published message count being the first one.